# Appending individual characters to char array and returning the char array

Tags: arrays, c, character-encoding, character, esp32

I am once again having a lot of difficulties with chars and char arrays in my Arduino program. I use ESP32 device with SPIFFS where I save some data which I want to save into my ESP32 device. In my SPIFFS I have a wifi.txt file where I save wifi name. I then call function:

```
char* saved_networks; // create char array to save information from readfile
saved_networks = readFile(SPIFFS, "/wifi.txt");
```

readFile function is described here:

```
char* readFile(fs::FS &fs, const char *path)
{
    char* return_message; //create a variable return_message to hold the appended char data
    Serial.printf("Reading file: %s\n", path);

    File file = fs.open(path);
    if (!file || file.isDirectory())
    {
        Serial.println("Failed to open file for reading");
        return "FAIL";
    }

    Serial.print("Read from file: ");
    while (file.available())
    {
        //Serial.write(file.read());
        char c =  file.read(); // save one character at a time and save it to a temporaray variable c
        delayMicroseconds(100);
        Serial.print(c); // this prints the wifi name as expected so everything is working ok up to this point
        strcat(return_message, &c); // append char array (return_message)

    }
    Serial.print("printing final return message before closing file system=");
    Serial.println(return_message); //prints loads of garbage
    file.close();
    return return_message;
}
```

After printing the return_message, ESP32 device crashes and returns an error message:

```
Reading file: /wifi.txt
Read from file: Telia-33F8A3-Greitas
printing final return message before closing file sysetm=x⸮?⸮⸮?⸮⸮?T⸮    @?e⸮    @?l⸮    @?i⸮    @?a⸮    @?-⸮    @?3⸮    @?3⸮    @?F⸮    @?8⸮    @?A⸮    @?3⸮    @?-⸮    @?G⸮    @?r⸮    @?e⸮    @?i⸮    @?t⸮    @?a⸮


Stack smashing protect failure!

abort() was called at PC 0x401377bf on core 1

ELF file SHA256: 0000000000000000

Backtrace: 0x40088740:0x3ffb1480 0x400889bd:0x3ffb14a0 0x401377bf:0x3ffb14c0 0x400d1685:0x3ffb14e0 0x400d1872:0x3ffb1590 0x400d18b3:0x3ffb1f80 0x400d4cfe:0x3ffb1fb0 0x400899ce:0x3ffb1fd0

Rebooting...
ets Jun  8 2016 00:22:57

rst:0xc (SW_CPU_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:1
load:0x3fff0018,len:4
load:0x3fff001c,len:1216
ho 0 tail 12 room 4
load:0x40078000,len:10944
load:0x40080400,len:6388
entry 0x400806b4
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

**UPDATE1**

Is this also the same when passing the char array to a void function by reference?:

If I declare my readFile function as following :

```
void readFile(fs::FS &fs, const char *path, char* return_data)
{
    Serial.printf("Reading file: %s\n", path);

    File file = fs.open(path);
    if (!file || file.isDirectory())
    {
        Serial.println("Failed to open file for reading");
        return;
    }

    Serial.print("Read from file: ");
    while (file.available())
    {
        //Serial.write(file.read());
        char c =  file.read();
        delayMicroseconds(100);
        Serial.print(c);
// Do I also must have allocated memory in order to append characters to my return_data char array

    }
    Serial.print("printing final return message before closing file sysetm=");
    Serial.println(return_data);
    file.close();

}
```

And then in my main, I call:

```
    char* saved_networks = NULL; // create char array to save information from readfile
    readFile(SPIFFS, "/wifi.txt",&saved_networks[0]);
```

**UPDATE2**

I have managed to do it by passing a char array as a reference. This method does not require malloc nor free.

```
void readFile123(fs::FS &fs, const char *path, char* return_data)
{
   
    int n=0;
    Serial.printf("Reading file: %s\n", path);

    File file = fs.open(path);
    if (!file || file.isDirectory())
    {
        Serial.println("Failed to open file for reading");
        return;
    }
    Serial.print("Read from file: ");
    while (file.available())
    {
        char c =  file.read();
        delayMicroseconds(100);
        Serial.print(c);
        //strcat(return_data, &c); //returns meditation error
        return_data[n]=c; //returns meditation error
        n=n+1;
    }
    file.close();

}
```

and main code:

```
    char saved_networks[100];
    readFile123(SPIFFS, "/wifi.txt",saved_networks);
    Serial.print("saved networks=");
    Serial.println(saved_networks);
```

This way of implementation makes much more sense to me. Why would I ever want to use malloc if I can pass an array by reference? This is way more simple to implement.

However, I still have one more concern. As you can see from the code above, I have initialized maximum length of my char array to be 100, however, I am not sure what will be the size of my SPIFFS contents. Is there any way to overcome this issue? I know I can just declare the size for example 10000, and hope that the contents will never get that big, but that does not seem like a most efficient way of going about this issue. I hope someone can comment on that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you append c to an uninitalized pointer:

```
strcat(return_message, &c); // append char array (return_message)
```

Since `return_message` is not initialized, this invokes undefined behavior, because `stract` expects a 0 terminated C string. So you have to allocate memory for the message, as well as terminating it with a `0-byte`.

You must allocate memory to append it.

```
char* return_message = nullptr;
size_t message_len = 0;
...
while (file.available())
{
    //Serial.write(file.read());
    char c =  file.read(); // save one character at a time and save it to a temporaray variable c
    delayMicroseconds(100);
    Serial.print(c); // this prints the wifi name as expected so everything is working ok up to this point

    return_message = realloc(return_message, len+1);
    return_message[len++] = c;
}
return_message = realloc(return_message, len+1);
return_message[len++] = 0;
```

Or if you know the size of the expected message:

```
size_t max_message = 100;
char* return_message = malloc(max_message);
size_t message_len = 0;
*return_message = 0;
...
while (file.available())
{
    //Serial.write(file.read());
    char c =  file.read(); // save one character at a time and save it to a temporaray variable c
    delayMicroseconds(100);
    Serial.print(c); // this prints the wifi name as expected so everything is working ok up to this point

    return_message[len++] = c;
    if (len == max_message-1)
        break;
}
return_message[len++] = 0;
```

You also should not return a string literal with a non-const pointer:

```
if (!file || file.isDirectory())
{
    Serial.println("Failed to open file for reading");
    free(return_message);
    return strdup("FAIL");
}
```

The caller of this function must `free` the returned string, when it is done with it, otherwise you create a memory leak.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain what is the purpose of this code : ```return_message = realloc(return_message, len+1);```

Comment: And also, would that still be the same if instead of creating a char pointer return_message I create a char return_message[100]. I would then create a char array with a maximum size of 100, maybe I then can avoid using a allocation?

Comment: If you know the size of the message or limit it to a known value, then it is more efficient than using `realloc` like I did, which is the naive approach, but not that efficient.

Comment: Yes that works indeed.. Could you please explain on a little lower level what exactly is the problem with the way I was trying to do it initially and why we need to manually allocate memory. Do I also must free the memory at some point at the end of this function ? If I free the memory, I wont be able to return the string, will I?

Comment: I updated the answer with additional info.

Comment: Thanks. I am also not familiar with what you said about not returing a string literal with a non const pointer. I have never seen strdup function in use. What is the problem of returning a message of my own choise simply ```return "FAIL" ```

Comment: A string literal is supposed to read only (depending on the architecture) so returning it via a non-const pointer means that the caller may write to it, which is undefined behavior: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/294748/why-are-c-string-literals-read-only/294750

Comment: Thanks! This is much more difficult than I have imagined! Is this the exact same thing when I want to pass a char array to a function by reference? I have updated my initial question see UPDATE1

Comment: I have also found a way to implement this by passing as a reference . That way I can avoid using malloc which seems like a better idea.. However, I am still concerned about initializing my char array to be the maximum size of my SPIFFS content since I do not know what will be the size. I need my char array to allocate however much memory it needs dynamically based on the contents of SPIFFS. Perhaps thats where malloc comes in handy?

Comment: @LukasPetrikas, then you should pass the size of the array, so to not overwrite buffers.

Comment: But what if I dont know the size? The string length inside the SPIFFS will vary

Comment: You must pass in the size of the array and use it similar to what I did above. You then return `len` which tells you how much characters you added to the buffer.

Comment: But my array is declared and initialized prior to the function call

Comment: You should open a new question as this is quite different from your original problem.